# Free module after tensoring with a flat local ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, vector-bundles, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $R$ and $R'$ be two local rings. Let $f:R \rightarrow R'$ be a local ring morphism and $R'$ is flat over $R$. Now, let $M$ be a finitely generated module over $R$. Suppose $ R' \otimes_R M$ is a free module. I want to prove that then $M$ is a free $R$-module. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A flat local ring homomorphism is actually faithfully flat.

Then, note that finitely generated projective modules descent along faithfully flat ring maps, see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/058S). Of course, for local rings projective = free.